# How can I aggregate data with categorical responses to get the percentage of each response type in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to get percentages of categorical answer types for different types of questions (TYPE). I have multiple responses for each type for each individual, with multiple, categorical responses (different levels).

> 1) each individual should be on a different row, and
>   2) the columns should be the  TYPES+Response Level, with the value being percentage of times that particular response level was given for that question type for that individual.

The DATA looks like this:

```
SUBJECT TYPE    RESPONSE  
John    a   kappa                       
John    b   gamma  
John    a   delta  
John    a   gamma  
Mary    a   kappa   
Mary    a   delta       
Mary    b   kappa  
Mary    a   gamma  
Bill    b   delta  
Bill    a   gamma
```

The result should look like this:

```
SUBJECT a-kappa     a-gamma   a-delta   b-kappa     b-gamma b-delta
John    0.33        0.33      0.33      1.00        1.00    0.00
Mary    0.66        0.33      0.00      1.00        0.00    0.00
Bill    1.00        0.00      0.00      0.00        0.00    1.00
```

Based on c1au61o_HH's answer I was able to create something that works for my actual data file, but will still need some post-processing. (It is also not very elegant, but that's a minor concern.)

```
 Finaldf <- mydata %>%     
 group_by(Subject,Type) %>%     
 mutate(TOT = n()) %>%      
 group_by(Subject, Response, Type) %>%     
 mutate(RESPTOT = n())     

 Finaldf <- distinct(Finaldf)    
 Finaldf$Percentage <- Finaldf$RESPTOT/Finaldf$TOT
```

Any help is much appreciated, also please with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not the most efficient way, but if you want to use `tidyverse` you can unite the 2 columns and then do 2 different `group_by` to calculate totals for each subjects and percents.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  unite(TYPE_RESPONSE, c("TYPE", "RESPONSE"), sep = "_") %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
  mutate(TOT = n()) %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT, TYPE_RESPONSE) %>% 
  summarize(perc = n()/TOT * 100) %>% 
  spread(TYPE_RESPONSE, perc)
```

**DATA:**

```
df <- tibble( SUBJECT= rep(c("John", "Mary","Bill"), each = 4), 
                 TYPE = rep(c("a","b"), 6),
                 RESPONSE = rep(c("kappa", "gamma", "delta"), 4)
)
```

**EDIT in reply to comment:**

I understand that you want to calculate the percentage by `SUBJECT` and `TYPE`, so the code would be something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT, TYPE) %>% 
  mutate(TOT = n()) %>%
  unite(TYPE_RESPONSE, c("TYPE", "RESPONSE"), sep = "_") %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT, TYPE_RESPONSE) %>% 
  summarize(perc = n()/TOT * 100)%>% 
  spread(TYPE_RESPONSE, perc)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some ideas. But I need the percentage for e.g. gamma, within  the Type a questions only. So the above code for John gives the percentages 25 and 25 for a_kappa and a_delta  and NA for a_gamma, but I need to get that 50% of the "a" responses for John are kappa, and 50% are delta.

Comment: So it is the percentage of Response within Type within Subject, right?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to write something that works with my datafile, but doesn't quite produce the output format I wanted. I posted it above. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried the updated code that I provided? Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Hi, that works with the generated data, but when I try it with my actual data frame it gives me e.g. 200 percent for some values. I'm not sure why. But with the work around above I was able to get what I needed. Thank you so much for all your help!